# Enabling nginx Chunked Transfer Encoding

Tags: nginx, git, chunked

It looks like [nginx 0.8.35 may support chunked transfer encoding](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES):

> Changes with nginx 0.8.35                                        01 Apr 2010
>
> ```
> *) Change: now the charset filter runs before the SSI filter.
>
> *) Feature: the "chunked_transfer_encoding" directive.
> ```

This is great, because I'm trying to get push git changes through an nginx reverse proxy to a git-http-backend process. Git HTTP takes advantage of chunked transfer encoding [for client-side efficiency reasons](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/8/3/2795094).

However, I can't get it to work. I'm using nginx 0.8.44 on Debian Lenny with the following configure invocation:

```
./configure \
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin \
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
--user=www-data \
--group=www-data \
--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \
--lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock \
--with-http_ssl_module \
--with-http_gzip_static_module \
--with-http_realip_module
```

And the following conf file:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://192.168.0.10;
        include     /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    }
}
```

And my `proxy.conf` looks like this:

```
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size    100M;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_connect_timeout   90;
proxy_send_timeout      90;
proxy_read_timeout      90;
proxy_buffer_size       4k;
proxy_buffers           4 32k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
```

(Originally I posted this [question to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222007/enabling-nginx-chunked-transfer-encoding) but [was advised](https://twitter.com/boredzo/status/18251381867) it's more appropriate to Server Fault)

Comment: You cannot have buffers as well as chunked encoding. Buffers wait to send data, chunked should send it immediately.

Comment: Apparently Nginx supports Chunked since version 1.3.9 (27/11/2012). However, I still get "411 Length Required" error messages when a smartphone sends chunked POST requests to my Nginx server.
Any advice?

Comment: Where you able to adjust the chunk size somehow or know which parameter does this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is an old question, I know, but it came up in a search for the problem (which I've spent the afternoon trying to solve).  Martin F's comment gave me enough of a clue to get it working!

The trick is to set `proxy_buffering off;` in your location block.  Assuming that your upstream server is sending back chunked responses, this will cause nginx to send the individual chunks back to the client - even gzipping them on the fly if you have gzip output compression turned on.

Note that turning off buffering may have other disadvantages, so don't go blindly turning off buffering without understanding why.

Comment: It finally solved my problem with proxying HTTP 1.1 web admin which I tackled for days. Damn. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest editing your question to clarify.  There is a big difference between chunked requests and chunked responses.  John Dalton's answer addresses the latter.  Git does both.

Nginx does not currently support chunked POST requests and this posting shows up high in search results on the topic.  Chunked POST requests are used when you do not know the amount of data being uploaded in advance and is frequently used by mobile phones.

The only working solution I found is this:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpChunkinModule

Unfortunately it requires recompiling nginx as nginx doesn't support loadable modules.

Comment: I agree: I'm finding that HttpChunkinModule is the only theoretical workaround... but it's not open to me in my situation. Does anyone know if anything else can be done? (Any changes since 30 Jan 2011?)

Comment: No changes that I know.  I just did an nginx recompilation the other day in order to enable this.

Answer (score 7):

On my case... i try a lot of things and finally only need add to configuration

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
```

And it works...

Comment: I had to add `proxy_set_header    Connection          "";`... original answer from -> https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,247883,247883#msg-247883

Comment: This worked for me as well. But I really don't understand why.

Comment: Update to my last comment.... this worked because my upstream server was using Chunked Transfer Encoding, which was introduced in HTTP 1.1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).  The default http protocol version for nginx proxying is 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers used to be valid, but this is an old question.

It seems like **Chunked Transfers are supported per nginx 1.3.9**[1], which was released mid 2013 I think.

[1] http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpChunkinModule